# Auto-deploy/reload a jar in weblogic server

Tags: oracle, soa, weblogic-10.x, suite

I am new to Oracle SOA Suite 11.1.1.4... Currently I am working on User defined XPath Functions. As part of this, I will prepare a jar file and need to deploy into weblogic server(10.3) domain lib folder(fusionmw\soasuite\11gR1\11.1.1\sp4\user_projects\domains\DOMAIN_NAME\lib). When ever this jar is altered, I need to replace this in server domain lib and restart the server to load the changes. But I feel this is not a good practice in production server to restart.

Is there a way to auto load updated jar into server's domain so the changes will reflect immediately instead of restarting the server.

Thanks in advance,
Swamy.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-deployment is a method for quickly deploying an application to a stand-alone server (Administration Server) for evaluation or testing. It is recommended that this method be used only in a single-server development environment.

You can run a WebLogic Server domain in two different modes: development and production. Only development mode allows you use the auto-deployment feature

To auto-deploy an archived application, copy its archive file to the /autodeploy directory. WebLogic Server automatically sets the application’s deployment mode to stage mode.

Answer (score 3):

#### Few words of caution when using autodeploy

- Make sure that the server is running while you are adding/replacing/deleting a jar/war/ear in the autodeploy folder. Otherwise the server goes out of sync
- Make sure the server is running in development mode otherwise the autodeploy folder changes are not seen by the server instance
- In case you are packaging your jar/war/ear in a windows system then deploying it to a weblogic server running in a Unix environment, the weblogic instance will fail to unpack/autodeploy the file through the following exception

  java.util.zip.ZipException: Error opening file - filename.war Message - error in opening zip file 
  java.io.IOException: error in opening zip file with  ... Message - error in opening zip file ....
- Read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13702/autodeploy.htm)

Comment: Is there a way to auto-deploy as library instead of application

Comment: Hi Sam! Could you clarify on the out-of-sync thing? I actually delete folders inside autodeploy when Weblogic is not running.

Comment: @LppEdd , please add and remove into the autodeploy folder while weblogic is up and running.

Comment: @LppEdd Out-of-sync means that weblogic runtime  will be using the older deployed app , meanwhile you have placed a newer deployed app in the autodeploy folder. This might cause unexpected behavior...